# Matlab Newton Method Abitrary Precision

Tags: matlab

I have implemented the newton-method in Matlab:

```
format long

f = @(x) [x(1),x(2),x(3)];


grad_f = @(x) [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]];

x0 = [0.01,0.9,0.9]
dy = vpa(grad_f(x0));
y = vpa(f(x0));
NumIters = 10;

for j=1:NumIters
s = vpa(dy\y');
x0 = vpa(x0 - s');
dy = vpa(grad_f(x0));
y = vpa(f(x0));
x0
y
end
```

Is this the correct use of vpa? Is now everything calculate with infinite precision? So if it not convergences it is due to the problem and not due to rounding errors (numerically instability)?

Comment: Is grad_f intended to return [ 1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1] regardless of input? Because that is what it currently does.

Comment: yeah this is just a test function. but this is the correct derivative of f. If you change f to something more complex you need to modify grad_f and then it depends on x.

Comment: I wouldn't say you have infinite precision. Based on these examples, it looks like you chose the precision explicitly. http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/examples/variable-precision-arithmetic.html?searchHighlight=vpa